# Pegar cada linha de um arquivo CSV

Tags: java, array, orientação-a-objetos, selenium-webdriver

Preciso pegar dados de um arquivo CSV e armazenar em um array.

Exemplo:

```
CAIO ; 0909;abacaxi
BRUNO;1231;maça
```

Tenho que pegar por exemplo a linha 1, e cada valor  de cada coluna armazenar em uma variável para jogar em uma função do robo (Selenium).

Do jeito que consegui quebrando o csv, quando armazeno por exemplo `usuarioDado[0]` em uma variável e printo, mostro todas colunas, porém queria pegar a primeira linha dessa coluna para armazenar em uma variável, depois mesma coisa com a coluna 2, aí no fim iria para outra linha.

Enfim, preciso armazenar cada valor das colunas da primeira linha em uma variável independente, e depois fazer a mesma coisa pra linha 2.

Isso foi o que fiz:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class capturaDados {

    private static final String VIRGULA = ";";
    private static BufferedReader reader;


     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

         try{
             String arquivo = "C:\\Users\\rioscai\\Documents\\AcessosBKL.csv";
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(arquivo)));
            String linha = null;
            while ((linha = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] dadosUsuario = linha.split(VIRGULA);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dadosUsuario));


                // System.out.println("Ambiente: " + dadosUsuario[0]);


                /* System.out.println("Grupo: " + dadosUsuario[1]);
                System.out.println("App: " + dadosUsuario[2]);
                System.out.println("OBS: " + dadosUsuario[3]);
                System.out.println("Perfil: " + dadosUsuario[4]);
                System.out.println("--------------------------");*/


                }
             }catch(Exception e ){  
                 e.printStackTrace();

             }
     }
}
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Caio, edite sua pergunta e inclua o código que você fez. Isso ajuda quem for te ajudar.

Comment: Amanhã irei postar , pois esta no PC do trabalho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caio, acredito que o que você queira fazer uma espécie de matriz com linha e coluna. Assim:

- linha 1

  - coluna 1: CAIO
  - coluna 2: 0909
  - coluna 3: abacaxi
- linha 2

  - coluna 1: BRUNO
  - coluna 2: 1231
  - coluna 3: maça

E assim por diante. Correto?

Então, acredito que você pode usar dois arrays, um para cada linha e outro para cada coluna, e juntar os dados em um único ArrayList. Tudo isso usando apenas o método split.

Primeiro, quebre seu CSV na quebra de linha (\n) para conseguir um array de linhas.

```
String[] linhas = csv.split("\n");
```

Agora, faça um loop pelas linhas quebrando no ponto-e-vírgula (;).

```
String[] colunas = linha.split(";");
```

Toda vez que você quebrar as colunas, adicione a um arrayList (que irá crescer automaticamente).

O código inteiro fica assim:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SepararCSVStackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // sua lista final será esta variável
        List<String[]> lista = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        // esse é o conteúdo do seu CSV
        String seuCSV = "CAIO ; 0909;abacaxi\n"
                + "BRUNO;1231;maça";

        // obtendo cada linha do seu CSV
        String[] linhas = seuCSV.split("\n");

        // passando cada linha do seu CSV para gerar as colunas
        for (int i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++) {
            // gerando as colunas
            String[] colunas = linhas[i].split(";");

            // e adicionando à lista
            lista.add(colunas);
        }

        // mostrando, por exemplo, abacaxi que está na linha 0 (1a linha) e coluna 2 (3a coluna)  
        System.out.println(lista.get(0)[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Opa , isso mesmo , irei testar amanhã no trabalho.Mas o que você disse é exatamento o que preciso.

Comment: Pois tenho uma lista de acessos em um csv ,ai fiz um robo que tenho que digitar tipo plataforma,ambiente e etc,porém nao estava conseguindo pegar a primeira linha,segunda e etc , só a coluna inteira

Comment: Obrigado , deu certo